# To route back previous component after routing with clicked object

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-routing

I have three components `header` , `list` & `home`

In `header` component  routing path for `list` component will be given like this:

```
  <div>
    <a [routerLink]="['../list']" >List</a>
  </div>
```

This `header` component is placed inside both `list` and `home` components.

In `list` component i am displaying some `data` in cards like this:

[image]

Now when the user click on the particular card,user will routed to `home` component along with the clicked object `id` like this:

[image]

**components code**

**home.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<h2>List Component</h2>
<div *ngFor="let contact of contacts" >

 <mat-card [routerLink]="['../home' , contact.id]"  >
    <h4>{{contact.contactName}}</h4>
     <p>{{contact.email}}</p>
</mat-card>
</div>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router'; 
import { ListComponent } from './list/list.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: ListComponent },
    { path: 'list', component: ListComponent },  
    { path: 'home/:id', component: HomeComponent },  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**home.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  public id: string;
   public sub: any = {};
  constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.id = params['id'];
        });
        console.log(this.id);
  }

}
```

**home.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<h2>Home Component</h2>
Clicked ID ==> {{id}}
```

Now the issue is:

- When i click on `home` components the url will be `https://XXXX-XXX-XX/home/02`
- Now from `home` component if i click the `list` (present in header component), then url is changing `https://XXXX-XXX-XX/home/list`

> How can i route back to `list` component from `home` component?

**[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-hrm7jz?file=src/app/app-routing.module.ts)**

Comment: use `router-outlet` for your requirements and move your `app-header` in app.component.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding:

```
{ path: 'list', component: ListComponent }
```

So your Routes will look like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ListComponent }, -- for default page
  { path: 'list', component: ListComponent },  
  { path: 'home/:id', component: HomeComponent },  
];
```

and HTML Code:

```
<div>
    <a [routerLink]="['/list']">List</a>
</div>
```

The problem with the current code:

You are using `../list` in which `..` means one path level up (so if you're on `/home/home.component.html` and you entered `../list.component.html` then it refers to the folder of `home` and then search for `list.component.html` file)

[`Forked_StackBlitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-zprtis)